# How I can insert case object as JSONB format via Doobie?

Tags: postgresql, scala, jsonb, doobie

I use scala 2.13 and doobie 0.12.1

For example,
I have case class

```
case class UserInfo(name: String, age: Int, hobbies: Vector[String])
```

I want insert user info in column info as jsonb

```
sql"""
        INSERT INTO users(
            id,
            info
            created_at,
        ) values (
            ${id},
            ${userInfo},
            ${createdAt},
        )
      """.update.run.transact(t)
```

In my DAO I have implicit val

```
implicit val JsonbMeta: Meta[Json] = Meta
.Advanced.other[PGobject]("jsonb")
.timap[Json](jsonStr => parser.parse(jsonStr.getValue).leftMap[Json](err => throw err).merge)(json => {
  val o = new PGobject
  o.setType("jsonb")
  o.setValue(json.noSpaces)
  o
})
```

But I have compile exception

```
found   : ***.****.UserInfo
   [error]  required: doobie.syntax.SqlInterpolator.SingleFragment[_]; incompatible interpolation method sql
    [error]       sql"""
    [error]       ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [doobie-postgres-circe module](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/tree/master/modules/postgres-circe/src) provides `pgEncoderPut` and `pgDecoderGet`. With these, and an implicit circe `Encoder` and `Decoder` in scope, you can create a `Meta[UserInfo]`. Then your example insert should work.

Example usage:

```scala
// Given encoder & decoder (or you could import io.circe.generic.auto._)
implicit encoder: io.circe.Encoder[UserInfo] = ???
implicit decoder: io.circe.Decoder[UserInfo] = ???

import doobie.postgres.circe.jsonb.implicits.{pgDecoderGet, pgEncoderPut}

implicit val meta: Meta[UserInfo] = new Meta(pgDecoderGet, pgEncoderPut)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the most correct solution for me!

Comment: Good answer! Let me improve it a bit: 1) sbt: `"org.tpolecat"  %% "doobie-postgres-circe" % doobieVersion`; 2) DAO: `import doobie.postgres.circe.jsonb.implicits._`

Answer (score 2):

You have defined a `Meta` for type `Json`, but it looks like you're using an instance of `UserInfo` in the interpolated string. Try converting the object to `Json` and passing it to `sql`:

```scala
// This assumes you're using Circe as your JSON library
import io.circe._, io.circe.generic.semiauto._, io.circe.syntax._

implicit val userInfoEncoder: Encoder[UserInfo] = deriveEncoder[UserInfo]

val userInfo: UserInfo = UserInfo("John", 50, Vector("Scala"))
val userInfoJson: Json = userInfo.asJson // requires Encoder[UserInfo]

// and then, assuming that an implicit Meta[Json] is in scope
sql"""INSERT INTO users(
            id,
            info
            created_at,
        ) values (
            ${id},
            ${userInfoJson}, -- instance of Json here
            ${createdAt},
        )"""
```

Comment: I am getting below error when trying to insert circe `Json` type to postgres `json` column. Any ideas?
```[error]  found   : io.circe.Json
[error]  required: doobie.syntax.SqlInterpolator.SingleFragment[_]```

Comment: My code snippet is incomplete, it assumes that an implicit instance of `Meta[Json]` is in scope. Does it help if you define an implicit `Meta[Json]` like in the question? Also, you may consider the approach described in the accepted answer, it requires less boilerplate than mine.

Comment: I do have a `Meta[Json]` in implicit scope. I tried the accepted answer but still getting the same error.

Comment: Ok, I got it working. It needed both implicit `Meta[Json]` and `Meta[UserInfo]` in scope for doobie to recognize the json mapping.